# How to enable PyTest HTML reporting from within the code and not from the System Terminal?

Tags: pytest, pytest-html

One way to generate HTML reports that I know of is by running from the System Terminal, but I want my code to handle it dynamically so that when I run the code from Terminal I do not have to pass the 
`--html=report.html` argument.

Comment: What do you mean by _dynamically_? You can put the option into `pytest.ini`, or set it programmatically.

Comment: I mean whenever I run my tests it should generate a HTML report in the end in this directory "./reports/automation.html"

Answer (score 3):

Create a `pytest.ini` in the directory where you run pytest. You can then place use the `addopts` variable to add default arguments when you run pytest. Something that looks like this:

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = --html=reports/automation.html
```